# Can't cancel set.interval

Tags: javascript

Checking for internet connection with the following code...

```
  var checkstatus = 0
  function checkConnection()
  {     
  $.ajax({ 
  url: "https://path/to/a/file.html",
  data: { method: 'checkConnection'},
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(html)
              { 
          clearInterval(checkstatus);
          console.log('connection available');
          return;   
              }    
         },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
       console.log('retrying');
       checkstatus = setInterval(function(){checkConnection()},10000);
         }
     });
 }
```

The line `clearInterval(checkstatus);` does not work as the script continues checking every 10 seconds, why is this?

Comment: You want setTimeout and not setInterval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. HTTP request is made
2. Error response comes back
3. Interval 1 is created calling checkConnection every 10 seconds
4. HTTP request is made
5. Error response comes back
6. Interval 2 is created calling checkConnection every 10 seconds
7. HTTP request is made
8. Success response comes back
9. Interval 2 is cancelled

… but interval 1 is still running.

---

Don't start the interval inside the error response. Either do it as the means by which you start the very first run of checkConnection or use `setTimeout` instead.

`setTimeout` is probably better as it will avoid race conditions in which the request takes more than 10 seconds to get a response.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` sets a callback to run every X seconds, and returns the ID of that callback. You're setting an *additional* callback to run every time your error callback happens, overwriting the previous interval's ID, but not cancelling it. When you finally *do* cancel an internval, it's only the last one you created.

Your error callback needs to test that `setInterval` hasn't already been called:

```
if (checkstatus == 0)
    checkstatus = setInterval(function(){checkConnection()},10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is easier if you would use `setTimeout` instead of the `setInterval` and you don't need to use the clear it then.